# Type annotation: dependencies between input and output types

Tags: python, mypy

Now I have a function:

```
def foo(a: List) -> Any:
    return a[1]
```

I need to avoid `Any` and have something like:

```
def foo(a: List[T]) -> T:
    return a[1]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's called [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")

def foo(a: typing.Sequence[T]) -> T:
    return a[1]

x = "a"
x = foo([1])
# error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str")
```